# htaccess rewrite to https is adding unwanted folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I don't normally use Apache and I am struggle to get a rewrite rule working.

The root folder contains a folder called public_html, when you browse to the website it loads as expected, I assume Apache automatically finds the index file inside the public_html folder. The problem I have is when adding the rewrite rule from http to https it adds the public_html to the url and a Not Found error is produced.

This is the rewrite rule I was using:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://exampledomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The url produced is something like this:

```
https://www.exampledomain.com/public_html
```

The desired url would look like this:

```
https://www.exampledomain.com
```

There are two parts to this questions:

1. Should the htaccess file be in the root or the public_html folder?
2. How do I prevent the rewrite rule adding public_html?

Any help would be greatly appreciated and if you would like further information or feel something is unclear please let me know.

Comment: Is there already a `.htaccess` in either root folder or public_html folder?

Comment: Yes .htaccess is currently in the root folder with the rewrite rule in it

Comment: Maybe my language was not precise :), just to be sure: was there already a `.htaccess` (before you added your rewrite rule), and if so, can you paste the contents of it?

Comment: Ah sorry I misunderstood, no there wasn't already an .htaccess file until I created one. The only thing in it is the rewrite rule.

Comment: Is that a shared web hosting?

Comment: Yes it is, through gridhost.

Comment: Does `RewriteRule ^public_html/(.*)$ https://exampledomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]` help?

Comment: When I was trying all sorts of things to get it working I had tried something like that but with a different condition, I used your rule with the condition above and it looks like it's working now. If you post it as an answer I will accept, thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is a shared hosting, there are probably some rewrites already configured in server configuration (like adding `/public_html` prefix to every request).
You can try to workaround with:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^public_html/(.*)$ https://exampledomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```